# play framework string format in template

Tags: java, playframework

I am using play framework 1.4.x, In controller , render a List object like this

```
List<Article> articles = Article.find("Category = ? order by id desc", cateId).fetch();
render(articles)
```

In views,html template

```
%{ for (item in articles) { }%
<div>
 ${item.title}
<li>${item.description}</li>
</div>
%{ } }%
```

but, the description is to long, need to do some kind of string format,or cut work,then show in the template.
I have already google for the template syntax but got nothing.

thanks for @Md Ayub Ali Sarker.
but I write a pure scala function in template , It throws a template compilation error.

[image: It throws a template compilation error]

It has fixed.
1.you can define a function in somewhere like utils.
2.in the views template,you can use these code call the utils function

```
%{hasBeenCuted = utils.Cut.cut(oginalKeywordsNeedToCut)}%
${hasBeenCuted}
```

Answer (score 0):

write template function in pure Scala code like

```
 @shortdescription(text: String) = @{
  text.take(10); // take first 10 character // more scala string function http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-string-examples-collection-cheat-sheet
}
```

in view change like this

```
%{ for (item in articles) { }%
<div>
 ${item.title}
<li>@shortdescription(${item.description})</li>
</div>
%{ } }%
```

Comment: Thank you,but in play framework 1.4.x, It's java not scala. Is this a problem?

Comment: yes but you have to write  template function in pure scala.